# what should be given back in an abstract java method if the object given back will always be a different child object created as an extend?

Tags: java, abstract-class, abstract

lets say you got a parent class called block that has a lot of child classes and has the abstract method called rotate that should give you back a different child of block. what should the abstract method "give back" if its always a specific other child object ?

i tried working around it but it unfortunately doesn't work with other options trying to just change the parameter i needed to in the method implementation of the child classes.

I have tried looking up any solutions or examples for this but i'm not quite sure for what to actually search.

lets say

```
public class Block{
     abstract public void rotate();
}
```

but instead of void what should i do to give back a different object extending block. if i got the public class T extends Block{} and the method rotate should give back the object from public class Ttilt extends Block{}.

Comment: `Block`. Program to the *interface*. Your question is both incredibly broad and incredibly vague.

Comment: okay i see this is really broad and vague sorry for that. i try to make it clearer in the post right now

Comment: tried my best is it a bit clearer know ?

Comment: tried my best is it a bit clearer know ?

Comment: @mingus2 Have you read my answer?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution should implement [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html). This would look like the following:

```java
public abstract class Parent<T extends Parent<T>> {
    ...
    abstract T method();
    ...
}
```

Your child class would look like:

```java
public class ChildA<ChildA> {
    ...
}
```

This will let you call `method()` through any of the child classes and that method will return an instance of that specific child class.